# Adding servlet to embedded tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Working with my first embedded tomcat application, so this may be a simple question.

I've created a servlet that I want to add to Tomcat programmatically in Java. My Driver class looks like the following:

```
    String contextPath = "/";
    String appBase = ".";
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();     
    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(port.orElse("8080") ));
    Context ctx = tomcat.addContext(contextPath, appBase);
    Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "HelloWorldServlet", new HelloWorldServlet());

    ctx.addServletMapping("/*", "HelloWorldServlet");

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
```

And my servlet has the following definitions.

```
 @WebServlet(
    name = "HelloWorldServlet",
    urlPatterns = {"/helloWorld"}
)
```

When I try running this, it tells me that I have a

```
java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Main resource set specified [.......\target\tomcat.8080\webapps\.] is not valid.
```

Am I adding my servlet correctly? Basically, I want to be able to go to localhost:8080/helloWorld and have it fire my servlet.

Comment: You are missing the context from your URL.  It should be something like `http://localhost:8080/yourWebApp/helloWorld`

Comment: How do I add that? And also, what exactly is the contextPath and appBase suppose to do? I assume somehow, I need to give Tomcat the path to my servlet class right?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem today:

Embedded Tomcat:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws LifecycleException
    {
        int port = 8080;
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setBaseDir("temp");
        tomcat.setPort(port);

        String contextPath = "/";
        String docBase = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();

        Context context = tomcat.addContext(contextPath, docBase);

        HttpServlet servlet = new HelloWorldServlet();
        String servletName = "HelloWorld";
        String urlPattern = "/helloWorld";

        tomcat.addServlet(contextPath, servletName, servlet);      
        context.addServletMappingDecoded(urlPattern, servletName);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();

    }
}
```

My Servlet:

```
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

        writer.println("Hello World!");

    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.48</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```